# How can I implement the code on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I would like to create an app that shows an animated sequence of images that change with OnClick of ImageView(not with a button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ViewPager`. See at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nL0k2usU7I8&t=793s